# Vba move row up and down with button except second row

Tags: excel, vba, select

Hay I hope you can help me to do this.

I need a VBA code which moves the row which has an activated cell up or down. the second column should be frozen not moving.

The data looks like [Data excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0To2.png)
the Priority should be freeze and the rest should move up and down.

I have this code but it moves the entire row.

```
Sub MoveDown()
Selection.EntireRow.Select
Selection.Cut
ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Range("A1").Select
Selection.EntireRow.Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Range("A1").Select
End Sub

Sub MoveUp()
Selection.EntireRow.Select
Selection.Cut
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Range("A1").Select
Selection.EntireRow.Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance.
Best,

Comment: Then just use a range? Don't use a whole row.

Comment: Why not put a formula like '=row()-1' into column 2?

Comment: Can you just put a formula like `=ROW()-1` in Columb B and then cut/copy?

Comment: Could you please tell me where exactly to put the =row()-1.. like which line @ValonMiller

Comment: `=ROW()-1` goes in all the cells in Column B from B2 to the bottom of your list.

Comment: Just to clarify:  Are you looking to move (up or down) an entire row with the exception of the value in the 2nd column?

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do @FrankBall. The code am using is moving the entire row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No formula change required in column B:

```
Public Sub moveRowUp()
    If Selection.row <> 2 Then
        'move the whole row
        Selection.EntireRow.Cut
        Selection.Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
        'move column 2 back
        Selection.EntireRow.Cells(1, 2).Cut
        Selection.EntireRow.Cells(1, 2).Offset(-1, 0).Insert shift:=xlDown
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub moveRowDown()
    If Selection.row <> 1 Then
        'move the whole row
        Selection.EntireRow.Cut
        Selection.Offset(2, 0).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
        'move column 2 back
        Selection.EntireRow.Cells(1, 2).Cut
        Selection.EntireRow.Cells(1, 2).Offset(2, 0).Insert shift:=xlDown
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: No problem, if this worked well, please mark it as the correct answer for this thread. Thanks!